# OpenAM 10 iPlanetDirectoryPro cookie change

Tags: security, cookies, openam

Several documents on the ForgeRock site mention to change the iPlanetDirectoryPro cookie name in openAM 10 but never mention which file(s) to change it in.  I've tried several including AgentService.xml and AMAuth.xml to no avail.  Has anyone does this successfully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to change it in files, the files you mentioned are 'OpenAM service descriptions' which are loaded into the configuration store when OpenAM is configured.

Later on you have to change the service attributes using either the console or ssoadm.

You can change the name of the SSO session tracking cookie by changing value in 'server defaults' under 'servers and sites'.

If you have Agents running in normal SSO mode, be sure to adopt the value there as well.

Comment: Thanks Bernhard!  ForgeRock should update their documentation.